# Left Floated Div not showing colour after clearfix

Tags: html, css, wordpress, clearfix

Yeah first off sorry to be a pain I've seen this question up loads already. It's just the answers that seem to work for everyone else are not for me.

Basically I want a few Div's to run as a tile style menu on a page of mine.
Similar to the windows menu I added a pic of. [windows menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm9bg.png)
I only want a maximum of 6 tiles in 3 rows of 2
I want them all to be the same size and filled with a colour that I can put text over to show which page they lead to.
My problem is the Div's are not showing the colour behind the text. They're only showing the text.

I tried the different clearfix methods on here first but removed them when none of them worked for me. No matter which one I use I still get this result: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urp3J.png)

The HTML I used is:

```html
<div class="TileMenuContainer">
<div class="TileRow">
<div class="tile first">My Bikes</div><div class="tile second">Dream Machines</div>
</div>
<div class="TileRow">
<div class="tile third">I.O.M TT</div><div class="tile fourth">Legends</div>
</div>
<div class="TileRow">
<div class="tile fifth">Rideouts</div>
</div>
</div>​
```

An the CSS I used before the clearfix attempts was this:

```css
/*********************** Tiled Menu Addition ********************/
.TileMenuContainer{
    width:90%;
    height:50%;    
}
.TileRow{
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
    height:auto;
    display:table;  
}
.tile {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 margin:0 5px 0 0;
 padding: 2px
 color:#DAA520;
 float:left;
}

.TileSelection{
    background-color: #483D8B;
}
```

If it helps the tutorial I was trying to adapt to suit my needs was this:
mrbool. com / creating-a-metro-style-menu-in-html-and-css / 26266
(Without the spaces because I don't have enough rep for more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
.tile {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 2px
```

You don't have a semi colon after padding - could be killing the styles falling behind it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is that you are asking help with, but the typo above could be the start and my input below is what I can further add.

You could also checkout [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for layout solutions.

I also created this pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPeByj) as an example.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing :)
Thanks a bunch I actually couldn't see it
Works fine with the semi colon